# OS password protect

Tags: security, operating-systems

My brother is an IT guy and uses my computer like it's his own. I have windows 10 now. The standard OS password will not work because he knows how to get around it. Google is useless to help. How can I REALLY secure access onto my computer even from an IT guy?

Comment: dear friend everything is hackable and crackable,simple solution put bios password and truecrypt the entire drive ,remember it can also be bypassed but will take some time,basic rule of thumb : anything with physicall acess was insecure

Comment: Al Gore had the right idea: a lock box so he can't get his mitts on it.

Comment: Given that the IT guy 1) works in IT and ought to have a sense of privacy, 2) is also your _brother_, can't you just ask him to keep his hands off your stuff? Punch if necessary.

Comment: What model is the computer ?  You are fighting a loosing battle, but if you are lucky enough to have a hard drive with FDE (Hardware Full Disk Encryption) and a BIOS which supports it, you might be able to put up a decent road block.

Comment: @grawity yes, this is almost an issue for some kind of Stack Exchange Interpersonal, rather than IT... though I don't think we have one of those (yet?)

Comment: @grawity this sounds like it could also be a generalised "How to keep a IT savvy person of my Computer?" but with a story attached

Comment: @underscore_d: Well you could say workplace.se (and perhaps parenting.se) come close

Answer (score 5):

Basic rule of security: Anything which has physical access was insecure

There were dozen ways to protect it but all have some fool proof solutions :

1. You could put a BIOS password  to secure your device

   Remember: BIOS reset was possible as mentioned over [here](http://ccm.net/faq/1192-lost-bios-password-resetting-the-bios), but you will got time to secure your device
2. Encrypt your drives with Truecrypt as mentioned over [here](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-use-truecrypt-to-encrypt-the-whole-windows-system), it can also be bypassed as mentioned over [here](http://truecryptblooz.blogspot.in/2011/09/one-day-i-forgot-my-truecrypt-password.html)
3. Another option if you worried about your brother might change some settings or modify something install a tool like [this](http://www.rollbacksoftware.com/) this will restore everything whatever he is doing

The above solutions were foolproof, but it will take some time to crack/hack into it.

Comment: From [Ten Immutable Laws Of Security (Version 2.0)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh278941.aspx): "Law #3: If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep him off your DISK, you can use Bitlocker to encrypt the drive with a password.  He will not be able to boot the Windows 10 instance without the password of keyed flashdrive.

http://www.howtogeek.com/192894/how-to-set-up-bitlocker-encryption-on-windows/

This will NOT stop him from booting it with a "liveCD" and using the computer, absent of hard disk as a linux workstation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.